# ADFS 2.0 claims transformation

Tags: sharepoint-2010, adfs2.0, federation, claims

I have Sharepoint which has configured claims based authentication with the adfs. ADFS is configured to use third party claims provider trust. So when user is accessing sharepoint he is redirected through the adfs to the third party identity provider login page. This identity provider (IdP) returns saml2 token back to the adfs and adfs redirect user to the sharepoint.

the problem is that third party IdP is configured to return only specific saml attributes (claims). I  need to configure ADFS to understand this specific attribute.

the custom saml attributes looks like:

```
<saml:Attribute Name="CustomID">
    <saml:AttributeValue xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">12345</saml:AttributeValue>
</saml:Attribute>
```

How can I use this claims in ADFS and then send it to the sharepoint?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Set up the ADFS / RP config. for the RP to pass through all claims instead of getting them from AD.